# Remove brackets from around quotation marks in string

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, series

```
d = {'1': (None,None), '2': ("ZRH","CGN"), '3': ("VIE","LAX")}
  ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['1', '2', '3'])
  print(ser)
        
  pd.Series(ser, dtype="string")
  patn = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", ser)
  strippedText = str(ser).replace('(','').replace(')','')
  ser = ser.str.split(',', 1).str
```

I have the following problem. I Have a pandas series, where the strings are in quatation marks ("ZRH","CGN") and i want to separate the panda series into two new columns without the brackets and the quotation marks. The problem is that the () are not inside the "" and therefor wont be removed.

My desired output is two columns one with ZRH and one with CGN. The code above is a sample and what tried so far. The only output I get is:

```
col 1 -> ("ZRH"
col 2 -> "CGN")
```

Comment: `("ZRH","CGN")` is a tuple of two strings, not a single string.

Comment: @BigBen No I need the add the separated strings to two new columns in the same dataframe without () and ""

Comment: @BigBen the posted solution does not return two new columns in the same pd.series unfortunately

Comment: @BigBen The whole data is in a data frame, but the column with the tuples ("ZRH","CGN") is a pandas.series, when printing print(type("column") -> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(ser.tolist()).add_prefix("col")
   col0  col1
0  None  None
1   ZRH   CGN
2   VIE   LAX
```

Comment: My inputs are the following: ('ZRH', 'CGN'), how can I split them up then into two new columns in the same dataframe just as VIE and VAR